# Can I install software in FreeBSD live CD?

Tags: freebsd, livecd

I want to run a few diagnostic scripts in a FreeBSD live CD (the scripts are for FreeBSD, so...). But I would like to monitor the HDD temperature while doing that, so is it possible to install any software (namely `smartctl`) inside a FreeBSD live cd-booted system?

As far as I found out, there is no `pkg` present in the live CD and all directories but `/tmp` are read-only. I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Use a persistent LiveUSB, such as is made with https://rufus.ie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that. But have you considered that you might have better options for your task?

Rather than the "Live CD" you could download the "memstick" version. So rather than booting a CD you would boot a USB stick and have a writeable system. And if the system is networked I would PXE boot a minimal image.

What you do not state but I expect you know is that you could download the `.tbz` file of the package and do the install using `pkg_add package-name.tbz`. As it by default tries to install into `/usr/local/bin` which is read-only you have the problem. While you could play around with `@option extract-in-place` you could easily run into post-install problems. You could also move the pertinent directories to a `tmpfs` filesystem. But it is not worth the hassle.

Your more reasonable options are:

## 1. Easy - simple copy

If it is a simple binary you could just ftp/sftp the file(s) into your `/tmp`. Then do a `chmod +x` on the executeable and run it from there.

## 2. Easy - NFS infrastructure

You could setup a NFS share on your network. Mount it from your "Live CD" system. Have your executables on that share and run it from there.

## 3. Intermediate but effort needed - Build your own.

As you note the CD is read-only. But you can prepare your own image. Then you decide which files goes onto the system. To build a system you need to have the FreeBSD source on your system. Then it is as simple as:

```
cd /usr/src
make buildworld buildkernel
cd release
make release
make install DESTDIR=/var/myrelease
```

You will then find the release images in `/var/myrelease` when done. The hard part is then to understand the system and where to make additions. You will probably need to set `SRC_CONF` (see  [src.conf(5)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=src.conf&sektion=5)) and you can learn a lot from [release(7)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?release(7))

If you do not want to make the full release you can simply do `make cdrom`.

**UPDATE**: I just happened by [sysutils/packmule](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/packmule/) which is a tool that helps you do exactly this. I have not tried it myself but it looks quite straightforward.

## 4. Intermediate but common - Build mfsbsd

Rather than starting with the official FreeBSD Live CD it is very common to use [mfsbsd](https://mfsbsd.vx.sk/) instead. It is a minimal system but very easy to work with. You can download readymade images from the homepage but you can easily [build](https://github.com/mmatuska/mfsbsd) your own.

It is easy adding packages by copying the `.tbz` files that should be automatically installed into the `packages/` directory.

```
mkdir ~/src
git clone https://github.com/mmatuska/mfsbsd.git ~/src/mfsbsd
cd ~/src/mfsbsd
mkdir packages
```

Now copy the `*.tbz` files to `~/src/mfsbsd/packages/` - then...

```
make iso BASE=/cdrom/usr/freebsd-dist
make iso BASE=/cdrom/12.2-RELEASE
make iso CUSTOM=1 BUILDWORLD=1 BUILDKERNEL=1
```

This would be my preferred method.

## Alternative: PXE

You do not state if you are actually booting from a CD. Or maybe doing a virtual boot with an .iso image in a VM. But for then kind of work you are playing around with it could quickly be worth looking into NFS (networked filesystem) and PXE (Network boot). Depending on your skill level it might be too soon but have a look at [PXE Booting Utilities With FreeBSD](http://www.wonkity.com/~wblock/docs/html/pxe.html) for a nice full description on how to setup a full environment. At the end it also describes how to boot a full FreeBSD Live system with NFS. This can give you some pointers to further exploration.

Comment: Thank you very much about that exquisite answer!! I was about to write *I will try to build an mfsbsd*, but then I read the sentence *The following packages are included in all mfsBSD ISO's: cpdup, dmidecode, ipmitool, nano, rsync, **smartmontools**, tmux* -- so I might just be able to **download** it instead. :-D

Comment: Yep! It is there. I do however hope you try building it yourself as well. It is a good learning experience. Try adding something like [sysutils/sleuthkit](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/sleuthkit) or [sysutils/ddrescue](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/ddrescue/). Maybe you could [accept this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it?

Comment: Of course I will. =) If I do not manage to try it during this Whitsun holiday I will accept your answer nonetheless.